# Itextsharp: Loosing graphics when starting new page

Tags: itext

Hi I have written a small report in iTextSharp using PdfContentByte. When I try to switch to a new page graphics are lost.

Currently I only have 2 pages. When page 1 is done, I use the routine below. All text on page 1 remains but graphics are lost. It appears as if document.Close does something that I need to invoke for page 1 before creating page 2.

```
    private void NewPage(bool firstPage)
    {
        if (!firstPage)
        {
            pdfWriter.Flush();
            document.NewPage();
        }
        pdfContentByte.Rectangle(x1, PageHeight.Value - (y1 + height), width, height);
        y = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please show how you do add graphics.

Comment: Hi, the rectangle in the example is lost. It is written on the last page though. I also draw lines and insert an image.

Comment: Hi, the rectangle in the example is lost. For the firstpage I call NewPage(false) which only paints the rectangle. When I switch to page 2 using NewPage(true), the rectangle and other graphics are lost. The last page which are terminated by 

    document.Close 

rather than 

    pdfWriter.Flush()   
    document.NewPage();

and then every thing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add

```
pdfContentByte.Stroke()
```

Then it worked :)